# How to open ipynb files into browser by double-click

Tags: python, browser, ipython

Previously, I had Canopy installed and at that time, I could simply double click on ipynb files and open them into the browser. 
However, later I needed Anaconda and once I installed it, this feature was gone.
Now I just want to be able to simply double click on ipynb files and the file gets open into the Firefox. Is it possible?

I read about this:
[nbopen](https://github.com/takluyver/nbopen)

```
pip install nbopen
python -m nbopen.install_win
```

But it didn't solve my problem. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Running `python -m nbopen.install_win` installs the executable `nbopen.exe` in the Scripts folder of your anaconda directory. For me this is:

```
PS> (gcm nbopen).Path
E:\Programs\anaconda\Scripts\nbopen.exe
```

The first line gets the path of the nbopen command (using PowerShell). If you are not using PowerShell you can find your conda directory by right-clicking on any (I)Python executable in your start menu and look at where it links to.

You can then associate the `nbopen.exe` file with the .ipynb filetype:

1. Right-click on a .ipynb file.
2. Click on Properties
3. Click on the  <kbd>Change</kbd> button next to "Open With:"
4. Click on <kbd>Browse</kbd>, browse to the path you found out and select `nbopen.exe`.

Double-clicking on .ipynb files now checks if a notebook server is running and opens the notebook. If no server is running, one is started in the active directory.

Comment: Worked indeed. Mine was at d:/Users/me/Anaconda3/Scripts/ 
Thank you!

Comment: What does the first line: `PS (gcm nbopen).Path` do exactly?

Comment: `gcm` is an [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-aliases) for the [`Get-Command` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command?view=powershell-6). This gives you inofrmation about a cmdlet or tool. With `.Path` you can find out where `nbopen` is located. I am not 100% sure why the `PS` is there, but most certainly it just denotes you use powershell and I missed a `>`. I corrected that.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this Firefox plugin. [Python Notebook Viewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/python-notebook-viewer/).

This plugin lets you view/render python notebooks without running notebook server. Once installed, set Firefox as default app to open ipynb files. From now onwards, you can simply open ipynb files by simply double clicking on it!

This saves a lot of time as most of the time developers are just keen on seeing a code. It also saves a hassle of browsing directories in Jupyter Notebook window to reach to a specific file.

Answer (score 0):

If [m00am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533768/how-to-open-ipynb-files-into-browser-by-double-click/49221463#49221463)'s solution doesn't work and nbopen.exe file doesn't show up then do the following:

1. Uninstall Anaconda.
2. Install Anaconda again and make sure you add Anaconda to Windows path during the installation.
3. Then try [m00am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533768/how-to-open-ipynb-files-into-browser-by-double-click/49221463#49221463)'s solution again.

This worked for me:)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32107570)