# nbopen fails upon "open with" command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've been searching for a way to open jupyter notebooks by double clicking on .ipynb files in Windows explorer, and I've installed nbopen since visiting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43533768/how-to-open-ipynb-files-into-browser-by-double-click/49221463) stackoverflow answer.

Jupyter notebooks run fine on my computer, and I can open a server if I navigate to the correct folder in anaconda prompt and type for instance `jupyter notebook` or `nbopen file.ipynb`.

However, when double clicking on .ipynb files (or "open with" nbopen.exe) I get the error messages displayed in the screenshot below. Apologies for the lack of a text version - the window disappears very quickly and I've only captured this by means of well-timed screenshot taking (incidentally, any tips on how to capture short-lived error messages like this in future would be appreciated). After the window has disappeared, nothing further happens

To try to resolve the error I have reinstalled nbopen but no success. I have also tried opening the .ipynb files with jupyter-notebook.exe, which duplicates this error message after `from notebook import notebookapp`.

The default python version (i.e. the first result for `python --version`) on my PC is Python 3.8.5.

[image: Error message]